# How to stop marker from rotation with camera movment?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a car that has LatLng and bearing and I get this info from the server.

The problem is when I set the marker car this is the code

```
MarkerOptions opt = new MarkerOptions();
                    opt.flat(false);
                    opt.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                    opt.position(latLng);
                    opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_driver));
                    opt.title(getString(R.string.text_drive_location));
                    markerDriver = map.addMarker(opt);
```

So when I rotate my fingers on the map the car moves with the camera, but I want it to do the bearing I get from my server, not my app or my rotate on map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
                    opt.flat(false);
```

Into

```
                    opt.flat(true);
```